# MySQL primary key column is not unique?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I have the following table in a MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE `datavalues` (
  `ValueID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DataValue` double NOT NULL,
  `ValueAccuracy` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `LocalDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `UTCOffset` double NOT NULL,
  `DateTimeUTC` datetime NOT NULL,
  `SiteID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `VariableID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `OffsetValue` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `OffsetTypeID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CensorCode` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'nc',
  `QualifierID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MethodID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SourceID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SampleID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DerivedFromID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QualityControlLevelID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ValueID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `DataValues_UNIQUE_DataValues`     (`DataValue`,`ValueAccuracy`,`LocalDateTime`,`UTCOffset`,`DateTimeUTC`,`SiteID`,`VariableID`,`OffsetValue`,`OffsetTypeID`,`CensorCode`,`QualifierID`,`MethodID`,`SourceID`,`SampleID`,`DerivedFromID`,`QualityControlLevelID`),
  KEY `FK_DataValues_Sites` (`SiteID`),
  KEY `FK_DataValues_Sources` (`SourceID`),
  KEY `FK_DataValues_QualityControlLevels` (`QualityControlLevelID`),
  KEY `FK_DataValues_OffsetTypes` (`OffsetTypeID`),
  KEY `FK_DataValues_CensorCodeCV` (`CensorCode`),
  KEY `FK_DataValues_Variables` (`VariableID`),
  KEY `FK_DataValues_Methods` (`MethodID`),
  KEY `FK_DataValues_Qualifiers` (`QualifierID`),
  KEY `FK_DataValues_Samples` (`SampleID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

ALTER TABLE `datavalues`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_DataValues_Sites` FOREIGN KEY (`SiteID`) REFERENCES `sites`     (`SiteID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_DataValues_Sources` FOREIGN KEY (`SourceID`) REFERENCES `sources` (`SourceID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_DataValues_QualityControlLevels` FOREIGN KEY (`QualityControlLevelID`) REFERENCES `qualitycontrollevels` (`QualityControlLevelID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_DataValues_OffsetTypes` FOREIGN KEY (`OffsetTypeID`) REFERENCES `offsettypes` (`OffsetTypeID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_DataValues_CensorCodeCV` FOREIGN KEY (`CensorCode`) REFERENCES `censorcodecv` (`Term`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_DataValues_Variables` FOREIGN KEY (`VariableID`) REFERENCES `variables` (`VariableID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_DataValues_Methods` FOREIGN KEY (`MethodID`) REFERENCES `methods` (`MethodID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_DataValues_Qualifiers` FOREIGN KEY (`QualifierID`) REFERENCES `qualifiers` (`QualifierID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_DataValues_Samples` FOREIGN KEY (`SampleID`) REFERENCES `samples` (`SampleID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

When I open my database in PhpMyAdmin 4.0.3 and run a query:

```
SELECT MAX(DateTimeUTC) from `datavalues`
```

the query executes but PhpMyAdmin shows a 
warning:

> This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox,
>   Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

How is it possible? I thought that if I have one column with PRIMARY KEY constraint then the column is UNIQUE. Could this be a bug in PhpMyAdmin? I'm confused.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't refer to current result set?

Comment: Are you certain it refers to this table and not one of the tables defined with a foreign key constraint to it? Maybe CensorCode?

Comment: When I run SELECT * FROM datavalues LIMIT 1 then the warning message is not shown. So it might be referring to the current result set and not to the original table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer: The warning:

> This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox,
>   Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

applies to the current result set and not to the original table.
Álvaro G. Vicario's comment is right.

This appears to be a new thing in PhpMyAdmin 4.0.4 and I find this type of message more confusing than useful.

Answer (score 0):

All you got to do is add a unique column like one called id with a index = PRIMARY like the pic, or if you have one already that is called id that are numbers just make it PRIMARY 
[image]